# Click on Element without ID - AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to do an automated login for several websites.
Therefore I use AutoHotKey.
To click on a Button or else I use the method ...getElementByID("...").

But very often, there is no ID in the HTML Code for a button.
For Example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" data-login="submit">
```

Is there any other possibility to click on this button?
Thank you very much for your reply!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByTagName('input');

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.